# iOS In-App purchase works in development but not in production

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I've just released my first app with iAP. It always worked fine in development, but in production it crashes when I try to make a purchase.

It seems like the app dosn't download my "product" in production mode. Have anyone else had similar problems, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: Download crash reports from iTunes and see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, will do that.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: I actually remeved the first version from sale to fix the crash. Have to wait until this new version get approved to be sure. If it was lag or not, will also download the crash report (thanks for the reminder).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In app purchase not working after publishing iOS app to App Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812352/in-app-purchase-not-working-after-publishing-ios-app-to-app-store)

Answer (score 4):

Recently I had submitted my app and it has a same issue. After spent some time on google I found that sometimes application available on store early and apple's production server takes time in updating products so wait for 24-36 hours. It will be automatically fixed.

**Edit**
Jagdeep has pointed towards a good point. Check status of your products it should be in "Approved" state. In my case it was in approved status.

- When you have created product you have checked the option "Clear for Sale"?

From Documentation : 
**Clear for Sale indicates whether your In-App Purchase is cleared for sale or not. If this box is unchecked, your In-App Purchase will not be available for purchase from within the app. Note that if you set Cleared for Sale to No, all settings for the In-App Purchase will still be available to edit in iTunes Connect, and you can change Cleared for Sale to Yes at a later date.**

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I also suspected that there might be a lag. Will wait and see. It is cleared for sale and all. It feels kinda emberrasing with a buy before you try and the app crashes when you want to buy.

Comment: Did this clear up for you?  We are experiencing the same issue, approved and cleared for sale but the in-app process doesn't work or crashes app in production.

Comment: Just an update, our issue magically went away so it seems apple is releasing the app and all in app purchases will cause crashes until we can only assume their servers sync.  Bizarre process and might cause headaches and user complaints.

Comment: Until product are not synch with apple's production server, you will not get any products. Somewhere in your code you are trying to access product array or something that actually doesn't have anything so,it is crashes. But you should handle it in your code there are lots of situation where you will not get products.

Answer (score 3):

#### It takes a little time even when everything is approved.

- My binary was approved.
- My In-App Purchase (IAP) was approved.
- My In-App Purchase was Cleared For Sale.
- Testing the purchase in development with a sandbox iTunes Account worked great.
- Purchasing in production with a real *or* sandbox iTunes Account would fail.

I didn't have to wait long, something like a couple hours and it just started working.

Now, my binary and my In-App Purhcase were approved at the same time and almost immediately after they were both approved, I released the app version to the store.

I'm not positive, but what I probably should have done was wait a couple hours before releasing that new app version and give the In-App Purchase a chance to "register" or "propagate" in the Production App Store.

Just a recommendation for others.

Answer (score 2):

Check your status in itunesConnect site -> Manage your purchase. Make sure your in-app-Purchase has been passed from review.