# In App Purchases Don't Work Once On App Store

Tags: objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have tested my in app purchases on my device and on simulators. The pop up to make purchases works!

My app was reviewed about 4 hours ago with the new in app purchase. Accepted!

Once on app store I asked friends to download it and the no ads button does not work. They do not get prompt to buy. I downloaded it myself too and nothing.

I went back to my local env and ran the app locally and the button works.

What could be the issue here? My code that magically it isn't working when its on the app store? Or because the app was just added a few hours that it needs more time?

Comment: As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31826312/6818278) , it takes some time to refresh/ propagate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In app purchase not working after publishing iOS app to App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812352/in-app-purchase-not-working-after-publishing-ios-app-to-app-store)